# Bash script performance

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu, performance

In a `bash` script, some integers in a range are generated, concatenated with fixed strings, and printed on a file. OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and `bash` version is `4.3.11(1)-release`.

The strings (and so the lines) to be printed are millions. Here is the hard disk usage from `iotop` in several times:

```
 TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND  
5701 be/4 myuser    408.24 B/s   97.27 K/s  0.00 %  0.23 % bash ./script.sh
5701 be/4 myuser    408.20 B/s   97.27 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % bash ./script.sh
5701 be/4 myuser    408.41 B/s   95.72 K/s  0.00 %  0.11 % bash ./script.sh
```

It takes about 16 minutes to print 1 million strings. Bandwidth of the hard disk is far away from being saturated. From `uptime` after more than 15 minutes of execution:

```
load average: 0,97, 1,14, 1,19
```

in a 4 core CPU. So, nor the CPU neither the hard disk seem to be responsible of this extremely slow execution.

1. How is it possible to speed up this process?
2. Is it possible still using `bash` or should I use another language?

---

Relevant parts of the script are the following lines:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
a='fixedstring1'
b='fixedstring2'

while [[ $i -le 9999999 ]]; do
[...]
    ur="$a""$b""$i"
[...]
    echo $ur >> exp1/file$m
[...]
    (( i++ ))
done
```

`file$m` is the `m`-th generated file (the script generates multiple files with a fixed number of lines instead of a unique file with all the lines).

Comment: i think `bash` is pretty slow....can you compare with the same done in `python` (or maybe even `awk`)

Comment: Shell scripts are generally really slow, but it's hard to tell without seeing your entire script whether the bottleneck is `bash` itself, the logic of your script, or I/O operations.

Comment: You can have a better metric whether its user or kernel space demanding by using `time` (1) command.

Comment: I think, multithreading may help you

Comment: This should probably be posted on [codereview.se]

Comment: Related: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: And [Is dash or some other shell "faster" than bash?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/148035) or [Is there something wrong with my script or is Bash much slower than Python?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/303167) Or to sum up, don't use shell loops, and if you have to, avoid bash.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you for your links and your suggestions. Thank you to all for their considerations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash loop is extremly slow in your case:

```
> cat test-1.sh
#!/bin/sh

i=0
a='fixedstring1'
b='fixedstring2'


while [ $i -lt ${1:-9} ]; do
  ur="$a""$b""$i"
  echo $ur
  (( i++ ))
done

> time sh test-1.sh 999999 | wc -l
...
real    1m11.488s
```

And using `jot` (or `seq`) makes it much faster:

```
> cat test-3.sh
#!/bin/sh

a='fixedstring1'
b='fixedstring2'

jot -w "$a$b" ${1:-9}
# seq -f "$a$b%g" ${1:-9}
> time sh test-3.sh 999999 | wc -l
...
real    0m0.613s
```

And what is the logic of splitting numbers to file? If it's simple limiting number of lines, you could use `split` command (right now I mean `GNU split` due to using `-d` option):

```
sh test-3.sh | split -d -l "how much lines in one file" - expr1/file
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so much faster than the other solutions. Yes, the lines are split into files in order to limit the number of lines in each file. Since `jot` is not included in some systems, this is the `seq` alternative in this case: `seq -f "$a%08.0f$b"`.

Answer (score 1):

You're repeatedly opening and closing the same file (maybe hundreds of times). Try to open each file at most once.

```
i=0
a='fixedstring1'
b='fixedstring2'
m=0

exec 3>exp1/file$m

while [[ $i -le 9999999 ]]; do
    ur="$a$b$i"
    if ... # m changes
    then
        exec 3>exp1/file$m
    fi
    echo $ur >&3
    (( i++ ))
done
```

This is the same advice as redirecting the whole loop instead of redirecting a specific command in the loop.

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to close the file descriptor (`exec 3> &-`)at the end of the script?

Comment: @WillianPaixao at the end of the script, where it exits? Wouldn't it be automatically closed then? O.o

Comment: It works even without closing the file descriptors. Thank you. It improves performance, but the other solution is a lot faster, maybe due to the absence of the `while` cycle, as pointed out by Fedor.